# Migrating JSON utils from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json

Tags: json, .net-core, json.net, .net-standard, system.text.json

I'm trying to migrate/update the `JSON` utils I have in my library class from `NewtonSoft.Json` to `System.Text.Json`.

What is the `System.Text.Json` equivalent of `TypeNameHandling`? Please see my utils method below that I'm trying to migrate:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
public static string Serialize(object obj, bool withTypes = true)
{
    if (withTypes)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, new JsonSerializerSettings
               {
                  TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
                  TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Simple
               });
    }
    else
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Google did not helped? https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm

Comment: This is not supported at the moment unless you roll your own `JsonConverter` for each class that you wan't to serialize: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/39031, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/37787